# Are there any known benchmarks/statistics on UnQLite?

Tags: performance, nosql, sqlite, benchmark

I came across UnQLite the other day in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403174/is-there-any-nosql-database-as-simple-as-sqlite) and it has me intrigued for some software I'm working on. However, very few tests have been published on how well it performs. [There are plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764710/sqlite-performance-benchmark-why-is-memory-so-slow-only-1-5x-as-fast-as-d) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778716/sqlite-insert-speed-slows-as-number-of-records-increases-due-to-an-index) and
[public](https://leveldb.googlecode.com/git-history/1.17/doc/benchmark.html) data available that help on SQLite and others but nothing on UnQLite. (I'm looking at serverless databases, hence my mention of SQLite. I understand that SQLite is relational whereas UnQLite is KVP and the two are not forked from the same parent projects)

I'd like to know:

- What UnQLite seems to achieve in read/write speeds
- What types of reads and writes (sequential, synchronous, large data, batch, random, etc.) it does well at compared to some other databases
- Where bottlenecking seems to occur
- How large the database tends to get (disk size or rows) before the time it takes to find and extract data begins to see a significant increase (i.e. slows down)
- If at all possible, what disk format(s) (ext3/4, NTFS, exFAT, HFS+) cause problems for the database
- Any recommended ways of optimizing performance with it

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have found some information and pointers [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150408013045/https://unqlite.org/forum/thread.php?file=document-store-performance-indexes). Extracts from that thread:

> ...retrieved records from a given collection a parsed only once (FastJSON) and cached in-memory for fast retrieval. The cache is a O(1) hashtable so performance shouldn't be a problem.
>
> ...only the first retrieval is a little bit slower than the others since it involve a disk access (In case you are working with an on-disk DB) and a preprocessing phase (FastJSON decoding) while later fetches are in-memory operations only with no decoding overhead.
>
> My Observations about document storage in UnQlite :
>
> In memory: Store faster, search slower ;But both slower than SQLite!
>   In File: Store slower, search faster
>
> e.g:- For same data, In UnQLite:
>
> In mem: store: 901.9 ms, search: 2586 ms
>   In Local disk: store: 15223.3 ms , search: 114.2 ms
>
> SQLite:
>   In mem: Store 9507 ms , Search : 105 ms
>
> Honestly, I haven't benchmarked SQLite indexes with UnQLite doc store. But, keep in mind that UnQLite is shipped with a *disk* KV storage engine that support nearly O(1) record retrieval.

The information given lacks specifics and context - nothing how the tests were conducted. Yet I believe it's enough to construct myself a vague opinion.

To me it seem that UnQLite has faster write but slower read performance, in relation to SQLite. It is probably a general trend when comparing SQL with NoSQL database systems.